Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController] does not exist
when I try to run the Laravel project, I get an error. I'm using Laravel 11.10.0 and PHP 8.3.7. I checked the namespace, class, and method names properly. I also tried commands like php artisan optimize:clear, but the error is still not resolved.
(https://i.sstatic.net/bZwKmBFU.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/jdp3ZAFd.png)

This problem is usually happening in fresh installs that's because there is no namespace prefix being applied to your route groups that your routes are loaded into
You would have to use the Fully Qualified Class Name for your Controllers when referring to them in your routes when not using the namespace prefixing like:
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
// or
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');

or App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider:
public function boot()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // <---------
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}

i hope this will solve your problem if not lemme know in the comments

thank you for the solution, but I used two methods of routing and still face the issue. I also tried to find the RouteServiceProvider file in the project, but it is not in the mentioned location. I have included an image for reference.

okay can you double check if there is no typos and then try to import the name space with use keyword like so :
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\PostController;
Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);
or fully like : Route::apiResource('posts', App\Http\Controllers\Api\PostController::class);
sometimes this can happen from autoloading issues try to run composer dump-autoload -o also
